# Boost on the Mac in Xcode fails lacking ciso646

Tags: c++, macos, boost

I have installed boost on my Mac using MacPorts. However, in Xcode including any boost library fails because in the bundled clang.hpp the (non existent) header file ciso646 is made mandatory on the Mac. Commenting this out in clang.hpp unfortunately causes an avalanche of downstream errors. Any ideas anyone?

Details: Macbook Pro 2016, Sierra 10-12-5, Xcode 8.3.3, Boost v1.+

Comment: Do you have that header somewhere?

Comment: No, it is not present, and I have not been able to trace the source anywhere.